# how to check value exist in object of array

Tags: javascript

```
var aclData=[
            {
            'Manage Users':
                ['add','view','edit','delete']
            },
            {
            'Manage Role':
                ['add','view','edit']
            }
            ];
```

How to check 'view' exist   in 'Manage Role'

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: i am found this  json data  in this format. and  i  want to check  the user  have  the  "delete" access in "Manage Role".

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
 for (var i = 0; i<aclData["Manage Users"].length; i++){
      if(aclData["Manage Users"][i] == "view"){
        // exists
      }
    }
```

**Edit:** Assumend you hava a dictonary. E.G:

```
var dict = []; // create an empty array

var dict = [];
aclData.push({
    key:   "Manage Users",
    value: ...
});
```

Comment: `aclData` is an array. It doesn't have the "Manage Users" property. Also, it would be much simpler to use `.indexOf()` instead of a custom loop.

Comment: Error: aclData['Manage Users'] is undefined

Comment: @sachinsaini It seems you are not familiar with JS. Please do some research before asking questions like this. There are plenty of tutorials and Q&A on this topic.

Comment: i am also try 
var aa = aclData['Manage Users'].indexOf('view');

Comment: @sachinsaini That's because it doesn't have that property, like I just said. It's an array. It's a very unwieldy structure. It would be best if you could build it as a single object, but if that's not possible, you'll have to loop over the array and search for the correct object inside it.

Comment: Yes @Derek you are  right.  what is problem in  my array.